# Run Mathrandom multiple Times

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a `setTimeout` function which prints a random number. However, when I run the snippet multiple times in a row in quick succession, the same random number is printed.

Where am I doing wrong?

Here is my function:

```js
function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
var t = generateRandomNumber(5000, 10000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("RandomNumber" + "  " + t);
}, t);
```

Comment: To keep most of your code you could use `t` as parameter instead of the outer scope one. Like `setTimeout(function(t){console.log("RandomNumber" + "  " + t)}, t, t);` is all you need to change.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the same result when you run the snippet multiple times because the value of `t` is being changed every time **but the value is not immediately printed**. Thus, when the timeouts run after `t` milliseconds, `t` will have already been set to the last randomly generated value.

See the following, which demonstrates what is going on:

```js
function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var t;
function test(){
   t = generateRandomNumber(5000, 10000);
   console.log(`t set to ${t}`)
   setTimeout ( function () {console.log("RandomNumber"+"  " + t);}, 1000 );
}

test()
test()
test()
```

You can solve this by storing `t` privately, inside a function for instance:

```js
function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function test() {
  var t = generateRandomNumber(5000, 10000)
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("RandomNumber" + "  " + t);
  }, t);
}

test()
test()
test()
```

---

To log one after the another with random times ([as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972142/run-mathrandom-multiple-times/74972160?noredirect=1#comment132303089_74972160)), you can call `setTimeout` recursively:

```js
function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const send = () => {
  const t = generateRandomNumber(100, 1000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Message: " + t)
    send()
  }, t)
}

send()
```

Comment: I assumed that the time for the first request would run the first time it was run. And the result comes afterwards. And I can immediately start the second request. how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Jeffrey you want the timeout to finish before generating another number?

Comment: @ Spektr  I would like to send messages one after the other, but with random times.

Comment: @ Spekt I like your code, never stop :-)
I'll formulate my request in more detail.

Wants to send Websocket messages. They should be outside the Mathrandom Function.
And if I set my variable t at setTimeout, this one should
always have new numbers